# HTC Wildfire S, intent of camera capture has a duplicate copy in Gallery in addition to the specified output in ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, htc-android

For security reason, I do not want the photo saved in the sdcard.
So after searching, I find a way to save the photo in the intenral storage.
The code snippet is as below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
photo = new File(this.getFilesDir(), BCConstants.CAMERA_IMAGE_NAME);
intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
        ContentProviderForCameraCapture.CONTENT_URI);
```

And it works for several devices, such as Nexus 4.

But for HTC Wildfire S, I find a duplicate copy in Gallery!

Why? I do not need a twin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the issue that many programmers met:
["Deleting a gallery image after camera intent photo taken"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390163/deleting-a-gallery-image-after-camera-intent-photo-taken)

Originally I just used the EXTRA_OUTPUT, but I soon discovered the following: - Some devices use it completely and skip the gallery. - Some devices ignore it completely and ONLY use the gallery. - Some devices really suck and save a full sized image to the gallery, and save a thumbnail only to the location I wanted. (HTC you know who you are...)

Hmm, you know who you are ... :)

Or see ["Android Camera intent creating two files"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515032/android-camera-intent-creating-two-files)